# Hibernate : convert mysql Query Datedif to HQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

here is my Query in mysql

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2008-11-30','2008-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

how to convert in to Hibernate Query Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way you can achieve this by extending mysql dialect and register it using [`registerFunction(String, SQLFunction)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerFunction%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction%29)

```
public class CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

  public CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect () {
    super();
    registerFunction( "datediff", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "datediff(?1, ?2)" ) );
 }

}
```

Comment: create above class and update your hibernate configuaration with CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect instead of MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you could get this specific mysql function into JPA/HQL (you can still use some native query if you want). A better approach would be using a third party library like `[Joda-time][1]` to  compute the number of days between two dates. I do not really see why we should use the database for this.